# Rails form_for with nested resources: "No route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, form-for, nested-resources

I have the following nested resources in my `routes.rb` file. The inner resource specifies a controller name.

```
resources :batches, :except => [:new], :path => "sets" do
  resources :tags, :controller => "batches_tags"
end
```

In the view for `BatchesTags#new`, I am trying to build a form:

```
<%= form_for [@batch, @tag], :url => batch_tag_path do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Attempting to load this page (`/sets/1/tags/new`) gives me a ActionController::RoutingError with the message:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"batches_tags"}

But when I run `$ rake routes`, it clearly shows this route *does* exist:

```
batch_tag GET    /sets/:batch_id/tags/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"batches_tags"}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

**Edit:**

In the view for `Batches#show`, I use that same `batch_tag_path` function and it works perfectly:

```
<%= link_to "...", batch_tag_path(@batch, tag) %>
```

Comment: You say you're attempting to load the /new action, but the router is throwing back an error about show... I'm confused. Whats the full output of rake_routes for batches and tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, while `batch_tag_path` *is* a valid route (making the "No route matches" error message very confusing), the path I needed was the pluralized `batch_tags_path`, as seen in this `$ rake routes` output:

```
batch_tags GET    /sets/:batch_id/tags(.:format)   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"batches_tags"}
           POST   /sets/:batch_id/tags(.:format)   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"batches_tags"}
```

Perhaps the error message meant that `batch_tag_path` wasn't a valid route for POST?